# Socket TCP em C

Tags: c

Estou com problema a fazer envio de um buffer de 32k de um cliente para um servidor. Por exemplo: eu tenho um programa A em uma máquina, que é o cliente, e um programa B em outra máquina, que é o servidor. Quando o cliente faz a conexão via socket, e envia o buffer, no servidor aparece que apenas 7k foram enviados, alguém sabe porque ocorre esse problema?

Código cliente:

```c
int sock, conecta;
struct sockaddr_in cliente;

char buffer[32768]

// PRENCHE BUFFER COM \0
memset(buffer, '.', sizeof(buffer));

// INICIALIZA O SOCKET
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Erro socket.");
    exit(1);
}

// ESTRUTURA DO CLIENTE
cliente.sin_family = AF_INET; /* IPv4 */
cliente.sin_port = htons(15678); /* CONECTAR NA PORTA */
cliente.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  /* CONECTAR NO IP */
memset(&(cliente.sin_zero), '/0', 8);

printf("\nConectando ao servidor %s...\n", inet_ntoa(cliente.sin_addr));

// FAZ CONEXÃO COM O SERVIDOR
conecta = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&cliente, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

if (conecta == -1) {
    printf("Porta fechada\n");
    exit(1);
} else
    printf("Conexao sucedida.\n");


// ENVIA BUFFER DE 32K

    enviarBuffer(sock, buffer, 32768);
```

Código servidor:

```c
/* CRIANDO ESTRUTURA LOCAL(SERVIDOR) */
    localServ.sin_family = AF_INET; /* IPv4 */
    localServ.sin_port = htons(PORTA);
    localServ.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* DECLARA COMO 0.0.0.0 PARA FUNCIONAR COM QUALQUER IP DISPONIVEL */
    memset(&(localServ.sin_zero), '/0', 8);


    if((sockServ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == ERR_CONECT_DB) {
        perror("Erro socket.");
        exit(1);
    }


    /* DECLARAÇÃO DO SOCKET() BIND() E LISTEN() DO SERVIDOR */

    if((bind(sockServ, (struct sockaddr *)&localServ, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) == ERR_CONECT_DB) {  /* ASSOCIA O SOCKET CRIADO À UMA PORTA */
        perror(("bind.\n"));
        exit(1);
    }

    if((listen(sockServ, BACKLOG)) == ERR_CONECT_DB) {  /* HABILITA CONEXÕES */
        perror("listen.\n");
        exit(1);
    }




    tamanho = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        while(1) {
            if ((sockReceive = accept(sockServ, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &tamanho)) < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                pid = fork();

                if(pid == 0) { // SE PROCESSO FILHO ...
                    close(sockServ); // ENCERRA PROCESSO PAI 


                    printf("Conexao recebida de %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(remote.sin_addr), ntohs(remote.sin_port));
                    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());

                    // RECEBE BUFFER DE 32K 
                   if((nBytes = recv(sockReceive, buffer, 32768, 0)) < 0) {
                        perror("buffer");
                        close(sockReceive);
                   } else 
                        printf("\nbuffer de solicitação recebido com %d Bytes\n", nBytes);


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de meter o `recv()` dentro dum ciclo até ele devolver `0`.

```
char buffer[40000];
int bsize = 40000;
int blen = 0;

while (blen < bsize) {
    int bytes = recv(socket, buffer + blen, bsize - blen, 0); // recv() dentro dum ciclo
    if (bytes == 0) break;
    if (bytes == -1) /* erro */;
    blen += bytes;
}
buffer[blen] = 0; // se o buffer tiver texto e quiseres trata-lo como uma string
```

Isto é necessario porque o funcionamento interno do `send()` permite que este envie pedaços da mensagem em **sequência**. O processo com o `read()` deve apanhar cada pedaço e re-construir a mensagem original.

---

Nota: o processo de envio de mensagem deve seguir um método semelhante com `send()`

---

Podes ler mais sobre [`recv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) e [`send()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) (em inglês) na referência POSIX.1-2017.

Comment: Legal, acho que deu certo!! Obrigado ^^

Comment: Outra coisa, esse loop também serve para enviar o buffer, ou seja, usar a funcão send()?

Comment: E também poderia explicar a necessidade de fazer isso?

Comment: Para enviar basta um `send()` com o conteudo completo. Se for necessario partir os dados em bocados, isso é feito internamente pelo `send()`, nao é da responsabilidade do programador.

Comment: Negativo @pmg  – o send() pode enviar apenas um pedaço dos dados, e é preciso fazer um loop tal qual o recv(). Ele não garante o envio de todos os dados!!! A diferença é que geralmente o buffer de envio tem espaço suficiente para receber 64k ou 128k de uma vez. Mas se você tentar enviar um buffer realmente grande, ou a conexão for lenta e o buffer de envio estiver lotado, send() vai retornar um valor menor que o buffer.

Comment: Obrigado @epx, nota adicionada na minha resposta.

Comment: @pmg no [livro referência de sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Network_Programming), a interrupção EINTR é tratada. Não seria interessante incluir isso na resposta?

Comment: Obrigado @lemoce, adicionei links para a referência POSIX.1-2017